# Swift: Search Firebase Data

Tags: arrays, swift, uisearchbar, firebase-realtime-database

I've been searching online and on Stack Overflow, but I haven't been able to find the answer to this. Especially because firebase has been updated recently.

I want convert my firebase database into a swift array that I can search through using the searchbarcontroller. This would be used to search through the usernames of my users.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let usersRef = databaseRef.child("users")

usersRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
        guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            return
        }

        let swiftArray = Array(data.values)
    })
```